# Return values until asynchronous method is finished?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, methods

lately I've had some trouble dealing with asynchronous methods. I've been getting around using setTimeout(); but I know this is neither optimal nor recommended. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have an asynchronous method inside a function and I want the function to wait until the async method is done to return the value. I have something like this:

```
    function myFun{
       var myarray = [];

       db.asyncmethod(function (){
          myarray.push("Something");
       });

       return myarray; 
    }
```

The problem is that `myarray`is returned empty because `asyncmethod` hasn't finished yet. How should I handle this?

Thanks =)

Comment: Return a promise instead.

Comment: You made me promises promises! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8Q83DPZy6E

Comment: What you want to do is impossible. You cannot turn an asynchronous call into a synchronous one in Javascript (and this is basically what you ask for). `myFun` consumes an async method, hence it should be async itself. And the best way to write async code is to use `Promise` as other have pointed out. Learn about it. If you have the luxury of using ES7 (maybe via traceurjs transpiler), using `async/await` is the closest you'll be to a synchronous syntax.